# obtener los objetos que se repiten en un array de objetos JSON con javascript (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array, object

Pongo a modo de ejemplo el siguiente array de objetos en JSON:

```
[{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"bbb","uns":"023"},{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"ccc","uns":"765"},{"id":"ddd","uns":"256"}].
```

Me gustaría obtener un array con los objetos repetidos (obsérvese que en el ejemplo se repite el objeto con id:aaa),algo así:

```
[{"id":"bbb","uns":"023"},REPETIDOS[{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"}],{"id":"ccc","uns":"765"},{"id":"ddd","uns":"256"}]
```

¿Cómo podría obtener los elementos repetidos con javascript/Jq?con un array simple lo consigo, pero con un array de objetos se me resiste.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Nos muestras el código que has probado y nos indicas qué te falla para poder ayudarte con él? Aunque en general, el truco sería pasar la comprobación de igualdad a una función por separado, y entonces el código de detección de duplicados sería igual para objetos compuestos que para simples.

Comment: Gracias por la rápida respuesta. He probado lo siguiente con un array de enteros:`var array = [2, 4, 13, 1, 3, 7, 6, 4, 7, 13, 4, 8, 4];
        var arrayOrdenado = array.slice().sort(); 
        var repetidos = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arrayOrdenado[i + 1] == arrayOrdenado[i]) {
                repetidos.push(arrayOrdenado[i]);
            }
        }

        console.log(repetidos);'

Comment: disculpas... no se dar formato al introducir el código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La única diferencia con el código que usas para sacar los duplicados de valores numéricos es que vas a necesitar:

- Para ordenar el array una función de comparación que decida si un objeto es menor que otro
- Para obtener los duplicados una función de comparación que decida si dos objetos son iguales

```js
var data = [{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"bbb","uns":"023"},{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"ccc","uns":"765"},{"id":"ddd","uns":"256"}];

var isEqualFunction = function(a, b){
  return a.id === b.id && a.uns === b.uns;
}

var compareFunction = function(a, b){
  return a.id === b.id
    ? (a.uns === b.uns ? 0 : (a.uns < b.uns ? -1 : 1))
    : (a.id < b.id ? -1 : 1);
}

var arrayOrdenado = data.sort(compareFunction);
var repetidos = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOrdenado.length - 1; i++) { 
  if (isEqualFunction(arrayOrdenado[i + 1], arrayOrdenado[i])) 
  {
    repetidos.push(arrayOrdenado[i]); 
  } 
} 
console.log(repetidos);
```

También podrías utilizar la misma función:

```js
var data = [{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"bbb","uns":"023"},{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"ccc","uns":"765"},{"id":"ddd","uns":"256"}];

var compareFunction = function(a, b){
  return a.id === b.id
    ? (a.uns === b.uns ? 0 : (a.uns < b.uns ? -1 : 1))
    : (a.id < b.id ? -1 : 1);
}

var arrayOrdenado = data.sort(compareFunction);
var repetidos = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOrdenado.length - 1; i++) { 
  if (compareFunction(arrayOrdenado[i + 1], arrayOrdenado[i]) === 0) 
  {
    repetidos.push(arrayOrdenado[i]); 
  } 
} 
console.log(repetidos);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Asier Villanueva.