# Comparar si llega repetido un un json

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs

Muy Buenos Dias, tengo una Duda quisiera realizar la comparación entre objetos un arreglo de objetos que tienen la forma:

```
{nombre : "x", proveedor : 100000 , cantidad: 1400.2}
{nombre : "x", proveedor : 100000 , cantidad: 1300.2}
{nombre : "x", proveedor : 100000 , cantidad: 1200.2}
{nombre : "x", proveedor : 100000 , cantidad: 1100.2}
{nombre : "x", proveedor : 100000 , cantidad: 100.2}
{nombre : "z", proveedor : 100002, cantidad: 1400.2}
{nombre : "z", proveedor : 100002 , cantidad: 1300.2}
{nombre : "z", proveedor : 100002 , cantidad: 1200.2}
{nombre : "z", proveedor : 100002 , cantidad: 1100.2}
{nombre : "z", proveedor : 100002 , cantidad: 100.2}
```

Quisiera tener una estructura algo como esto [{nombre : x , proveedor : 100000 , cantidad (suma de la cantidad)}] y en mi iteración guardarlos sin que se repitan los proveedores ni el nombre y sumar la cantidad.

En resumen, agrupar por proveedor y nombre.

Comment: Aqui hay algo similar a tu pregunta.. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76231/obtener-los-objetos-que-se-repiten-en-un-array-de-objetos-json-con-javascript-

Comment: ¿Cada nombre siempre está relacionado a un mismo proveedor?

Comment: asi es amigo , el proveedor es como si fuera su ID solo que son las ordenes y cantidades, pero me llegan repetidos  lo que quiero es obtener solo uno mediante un for in armar una estrucutra y meter el nombre del proveeedor su id y su cantidad sumandolo

Comment: Objeto Javascript != JSON

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primero iteramos por todos los objetos y vamos almacenando los datos una vez cada uno en un objeto temporal. El truco aquí lo hace el condicional `if (!_cantidadPorProveedor.hasOwnProperty(objetos[i].nombre))...`, es decir, si `_cantidadPorProveedor` no tiene aún guardado el nombre, lo incluimos. Esto te garantizará que no aparecen objetos repetidos.

La segunda iteración es para convertir los datos de `_cantidadPorProveedor` en un array, tal y como quieres la salida.

```js
var objetos = [
  {nombre : "x", proveedor: 100000, cantidad: 1400.2},
  {nombre : "x", proveedor: 100000, cantidad: 1300.2},
  {nombre : "x", proveedor: 100000, cantidad: 1200.2},
  {nombre : "x", proveedor: 100000, cantidad: 1100.2},
  {nombre : "x", proveedor: 100000, cantidad: 100.2},
  {nombre : "z", proveedor: 100002, cantidad: 1400.2},
  {nombre : "z", proveedor: 100002, cantidad: 1300.2},
  {nombre : "z", proveedor: 100002, cantidad: 1200.2},
  {nombre : "z", proveedor: 100002, cantidad: 1100.2},
  {nombre : "z", proveedor: 100002, cantidad: 100.2},
]

var resultados = [];

var _cantidadPorProveedor = {};

for (var i=0; i<objetos.length; i++) {
    if (!_cantidadPorProveedor.hasOwnProperty(objetos[i].nombre)) {
        _cantidadPorProveedor[objetos[i].nombre] = {
            "proveedor": objetos[i].proveedor,
            "cantidad": 0,
        }
    }
    _cantidadPorProveedor[objetos[i].nombre]["cantidad"] += objetos[i].cantidad;
}

for (var nombre in _cantidadPorProveedor) {
    resultados.push({
        "nombre": nombre,
        "cantidad": _cantidadPorProveedor[nombre]["cantidad"],
        "proveedor": _cantidadPorProveedor[nombre]["proveedor"],
    })
}

console.log(resultados);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Pero un simple ***Ahí lo llevas*** y código sin explicación no es muy buena respuesta. Te invito a leer [answer], recuerda que una buena respuesta ayuda a la comunidad a crecer en conocimiento y también sube tu reputación al ser votada positivamente. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, editado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias , hazta el momento creo que es lo correcto , habia hecho algo asi pero en PHP , en Js , se me hacia dificil.

Comment: De nada, un placer.